# few kafka stream tasks stopped running in a stream application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a **Stream Topology with 2 source topics, 3 processors, 5 state stores and 4 sink topics**.
Those two topics have **12 partitions**.
Our application is **running in kubernetes**. It has three pods and so we have 3 instances of this streams running in one pod each.
When we install the application the rebalancing happens and the stream instances in the three pod goes to running state with 4 tasks each.
*These streams work fine* consuming events, updating the state store and producing messages through sinks.
But some times **message consumption from some partitions is stopped in one or two stream instances**.Message consumption of other partitions in the same instance goes fine. So I think that the corresponding **tasks suddenly stopped running** in those pods. There is no warning or error messages in streams client's log files.

**Edited: Added Section:**
As there is no consumer join request or rebalance triggered I think the tasks are running but some how no records are consumed.

There are two log messages after this.

*17:43:44.105 [kafka-admin-client-thread | XXXXX-admin] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=XXXXX-admin] Node -1 disconnected.*

*17:42:45.050 [XXXXX-StreamThread-1] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [XXXXX-StreamThread-1] Processed 11036 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 45 total tasks since the last update*

what could be the reason for that? I could not find the root cause and am out of ideas. Could some one please help.

we are using kafka-streams-3.1.1.

we have the config: **session.timeout.ms: 10000**

```
StreamsConfig values: 
    acceptable.recovery.lag = 10000
    application.id = XXXXX
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = XXXXX
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    built.in.metrics.version = latest
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = 
    commit.interval.ms = 1000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
    default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.list.key.serde.inner = null
    default.list.key.serde.type = null
    default.list.value.serde.inner = null
    default.list.value.serde.type = null
    default.production.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DefaultProductionExceptionHandler
    default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
    default.value.serde = null
    max.task.idle.ms = 0
    max.warmup.replicas = 2
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    num.standby.replicas = 0
    num.stream.threads = 1
    poll.ms = 50
    probing.rebalance.interval.ms = 600000
    processing.guarantee = at_least_once
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    replication.factor = 3
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    rocksdb.config.setter = null
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
    state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
    task.timeout.ms = 300000
    topology.optimization = none
    upgrade.from = null
    window.size.ms = null
    windowed.inner.class.serde = null
    windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
```

Comment: I dont know if anything to do with thes two known issues:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13310, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14024